# How to replace old FindAs<Type> in new MongoDB C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I should change version of MongoDB but I am a lot struggling and have a lot of questions. One of them is I had the method [FindAs<>()](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoCollection_FindAs__1.htm) but now it is part of legacy code and I should return that type that is already defined. I tried with method ***Find(query)*** and to somehow cast the return value, but it was unsuccessful. The part of code I want to change is the following:

```
GetCollection(GetCollectionName(collectionName), federatedDBKey)
                .FindAs<BsonDocument>(query)
                .SetFields(map.ElementName)
                .AsQueryable()
                .First();
```

This part *AsQueryable()* I replaced with:

```
IMongoCollectionExtensions.AsQueryable<T>(GetCollection(GetCollectionName(collectionName), federatedDBKey))
            .First();
```

But the other code I don't know how as ***SetFields*** also doesn't exist anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `FindAs` with a `Find` followed by `As`. Instead of using `SetFields`, you can use `Project`:

```
GetCollection(GetCollectionName(collectionName), federatedDBKey)
    .Find(queryToGetSingleSubEntity)
    .As<BsonDocument>()
    .Project<T, BsonDocument>(Builders<T>.Projection.Include(map.ElementName))
    .First();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It helped me in some part, but in this version I am using (2.17) I got the following error: 'IMongoCollection<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Find' and the best extension method overload 'IMongoCollectionExtensions.Find<BsonDocument>(IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>, FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>, FindOptions)' requires a receiver of type 'IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>' is this my mistake or because of versions?

Comment: What is the type of your collection? In the sample, I've used `Find<BsonDocument>(...)`, but `Find(...)` should work as well. I've updated the code accordingly.

Comment: It is **IMongoCollection** as I return it from: MongoDbManager.GetDatabase(federatedDBKey).GetCollection<T>(collectionName);

Comment: If you write only `Find(query)`, does that work? What is `T` in your call to `GetCollection<T>(collectionName)`?

Comment: If I write only **Find(query)** it raises error in **Project** method: The type arguments for method 'IFindFluent<T, BsonDocument>.Project<TNewProjection>(ProjectionDefinition<T, TNewProjection>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

That part with **GetCollection<T>(collectionName)** is used to make a repository type pattern for generic types so we can reuse code for more common operations.

Comment: What is the exact type of your collection that is returned from `GetCollection`, especially the **T** in `IMongoCollection<T>`?

Comment: I put another comment in this question so you can see how the GetCollection method is written. Maybe it is wrong as I inherited it from another programmer and I am a little bit inexperienced in MongoDB in C#

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248201/discussion-between-markus-and-newcsharp).